# Bulk Collect with million rows to insert.......Missing Rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to insert all the rows from the cursor to a table.But it is not inserting all the rows.Only some rows gets inserted.Please help
         I have created a procedure BPS_SPRDSHT which takes input as 3 parameters.

```
PROCEDURE BPS_SPRDSHT(p_period_name VARCHAR2,p_currency_code VARCHAR2,p_source_name VARCHAR2)
IS          
     CURSOR c_sprdsht
     IS
     SELECT gcc.segment1 AS company, gcc.segment6 AS prod_seg, gcc.segment2 dept,
       gcc.segment3 accnt, gcc.segment4 prd_grp, gcc.segment5 projct,
       gcc.segment7 future2, gljh.period_name,gljh.je_source,NULL NULL1,NULL NULL2,NULL NULL3,NULL NULL4,gljh.currency_code Currency, 
       gjlv.entered_dr,gjlv.entered_cr, gjlv.accounted_dr, gjlv.accounted_cr,gljh.currency_conversion_date,
       NULL NULL6,gljh.currency_conversion_rate ,NULL NULL8,NULL NULL9,NULL NULL10,NULL NULL11,NULL NULL12,NULL NULL13,NULL NULL14,NULL NULL15,
       gljh.je_category ,NULL NULL17,NULL NULL18,NULL NULL19,tax_code
  FROM gl_je_lines_v gjlv, gl_code_combinations gcc, gl_je_headers gljh
 WHERE gjlv.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id
   AND gljh.je_header_id = gjlv.je_header_id
   AND gljh.currency_code!='STAT'
   AND gljh.currency_code=NVL (p_currency_code, gljh.currency_code)
   AND gljh.period_name =  NVL (p_period_name, gljh.period_name)
   AND gljh.je_source LIKE  p_source_name||'%';

type t_spr is table of c_sprdsht%rowtype;
v_t_spr   t_spr :=t_spr();

BEGIN 
OPEN c_sprdsht;
LOOP
FETCH c_sprdsht BULK COLLECT INTO v_t_spr limit 50000;
EXIT WHEN c_sprdsht%notfound;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_sprdsht;



FND_FILE.PUT_LINE(FND_FILE.OUTPUT,'TOTAL ROWS FETCHED FOR SPREADSHEETS- '|| v_t_spr.count);


    IF v_t_spr.count > 0 THEN
        BEGIN
        FORALL I IN v_t_spr.FIRST..v_t_spr.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
            INSERT INTO custom.pwr_bps_gl_register 
            VALUES v_t_spr(i);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
                     fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output,'Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
                      FOR l IN 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || l || 
                                ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(l).error_index ||
                                    ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(l).ERROR_CODE));
                      END LOOP;
        END;  



    END IF;   

fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output,'END TIME: '||TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
END BPS_SPRDSHT;
```

Total rows to be inserted=568388
No of rows getting inserted=48345.

Comment: Why do you not just use SQL to insert the rows?

Comment: To improve the performance,I am using bulk collect as there are many rows.

Comment: @Nikhil And who told you `PL/SQL` is faster than plain `SQL`? Do it in SQL.

Comment: Nikhil and David are right by the way http://stackoverflow.com/a/2673550/105282

Comment: Not just a performance implication, but a code robustness issue. Here you have introduced an error that would have been impossible with a SQL-based solution.

Comment: @booyaa Not Nikhil, but I and David :-) Nikhil is the OP...lol

Comment: These comments are incomplete without mentioning that prefixing parameters with "p_" is just a hack for namespacing your PL/SQL variables when they're used in a SQL statement. Drop the prefix, and then use the namespace: "AND gljh.currency_code=NVL (BPS_SPRDSHT.currency_code, gljh.currency_code)". Also, use Coalesce() in preference to Nvl() -- more flexible, ANSI compliant, and uses short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @LalitKumarB apologies! :D

Comment: I usually prefer `i_` and `o_` for the `IN` and `OUT` parameters respectively.

Comment: @LalitKumarB You will have noticed that Oracle's own procedures and functions do not follow either of those prefixing practices.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes, agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle uses two engines to process PL/SQL code. All procedural code is handled by the **PL/SQL engine** while all SQL is handled by the SQL statement executor, or **SQL engine**. There is an overhead associated with each **context switch** between the two engines.

The entire **PL/SQL** code could be written in plain **SQL** which will be much **faster** and **lesser code**.

```
INSERT INTO custom.pwr_bps_gl_register
SELECT gcc.segment1 AS company,
  gcc.segment6      AS prod_seg,
  gcc.segment2 dept,
  gcc.segment3 accnt,
  gcc.segment4 prd_grp,
  gcc.segment5 projct,
  gcc.segment7 future2,
  gljh.period_name,
  gljh.je_source,
  NULL NULL1,
  NULL NULL2,
  NULL NULL3,
  NULL NULL4,
  gljh.currency_code Currency,
  gjlv.entered_dr,
  gjlv.entered_cr,
  gjlv.accounted_dr,
  gjlv.accounted_cr,
  gljh.currency_conversion_date,
  NULL NULL6,
  gljh.currency_conversion_rate ,
  NULL NULL8,
  NULL NULL9,
  NULL NULL10,
  NULL NULL11,
  NULL NULL12,
  NULL NULL13,
  NULL NULL14,
  NULL NULL15,
  gljh.je_category ,
  NULL NULL17,
  NULL NULL18,
  NULL NULL19,
  tax_code
FROM gl_je_lines_v gjlv,
  gl_code_combinations gcc,
  gl_je_headers gljh
WHERE gjlv.code_combination_id = gcc.code_combination_id
AND gljh.je_header_id          = gjlv.je_header_id
AND gljh.currency_code!        ='STAT'
AND gljh.currency_code         =NVL (p_currency_code, gljh.currency_code)
AND gljh.period_name           = NVL (p_period_name, gljh.period_name)
AND gljh.je_source LIKE p_source_name
  ||'%';
```

**Update**

It is a myth that **frequent commits* in PL/SQL is good for performance.

Thomas Kyte explained it beautifully [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022):

> Frequent commits -- sure, "frees up" that undo -- which invariabley
>   leads to ORA-1555  and the failure of your process.  Thats good for
>   performance right?
>
> Frequent commits -- sure, "frees up" locks -- which throws
>   transactional integrity out  the window.  Thats great for data
>   integrity right?
>
> Frequent commits -- sure "frees up" redo log buffer space -- by
>   forcing you to WAIT for  a sync write to the file system every time --
>   you WAIT and WAIT and WAIT.  I can see  how that would "increase
>   performance" (NOT).  Oh yeah, the fact that the redo buffer is 
>   flushed in the background
>
> - every three seconds
> - when 1/3 full
> - when 1meg full
>
> would do the same thing (free up this resource) AND not make you wait.
>
> - frequent commits -- there is NO resource to free up -- undo is undo,
>     big old circular  buffer.  It is not any harder for us to manage 15
>     gigawads or 15 bytes of undo.  Locks --  well, they are an attribute
>     of the data itself, it is no more expensive in Oracle (it  would be in
>     db2, sqlserver, informix, etc) to have one BILLION locks vs one lock. 
>     The  redo log buffer -- that is continously taking care of itself,
>     regardless of whether you  commit or not.

Comment: @Lalit-Thanks .I think plain SQL is much better and faster in my case.

Comment: @Nikhil Use PL/SQL when it is really required, else SQL has many features to do complex things. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

First of all let me point out that there is a serious bug in the code you are using: that is the reason for which you are not inserting all the records:

```
 BEGIN 
    OPEN c_sprdsht;
 LOOP
     FETCH c_sprdsht 
     BULK COLLECT INTO v_t_spr -- this OVERWRITES your array! 
                               -- it does not add new records!
     limit 50000;
     EXIT WHEN c_sprdsht%notfound;
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE c_sprdsht;
```

Each iteration OVERWRITES the contents of v_t_spr with the next 50,000 rows to be read.
 Actually the 48345 records you are inserting are simply the last block read during the last iteration.

the "insert" statemend should be inside the same loop: you should do an insert for each 50,000 rows read.

you should have written it this way:

```
BEGIN 
   OPEN c_sprdsht;
   LOOP
   FETCH c_sprdsht BULK COLLECT INTO v_t_spr limit 50000;
   EXIT WHEN c_sprdsht%notfound;

   FORALL I IN v_t_spr.FIRST..v_t_spr.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
          INSERT INTO custom.pwr_bps_gl_register 
          VALUES v_t_spr(i);
   ...
   ...  

END LOOP;
CLOSE c_sprdsht;
```

If you were expecting to have the whole table loaded in memory for doing just one unique insert, then you wouldn't have needed any loop or any "limit 50000" clause... and actually you could have used simply the "insert ... select" approach.

Now: a VERY GOOD reason for NOT using a "insert ... select" could be that there are so many rows in the source table that such insert would make the rollback segments grow so much that there is simply not enough phisical space on your server to hold them. But if this is the issue (you can't have so much rollback data for a single transaction), you should also perform a COMMIT for each 50,000 records block, otherwise your loop would not solve the problem: it would just be slower than the "insert ... select" and it would generate the same "out of rollback space" error (now i don't remember the exact error message...)

now, issuing a commit every 50,000 records is not the nicest thing to do, but if your system actually is not big enough to handle the needed rollback space, you have no other way out (or at least I am not aware of other way outs...)

Comment: If you don't have sufficient undo space for your operation, the solution is to increase the undo space, not to start committing inside a cursor.

Comment: If you are handling tables that contain thousands of millions of records maybe your customer is not willing to buy another 20.000 dollars of storage space just because you need to copy data from a table onto another...

Comment: @CarloSirna Frequent commits isn't a good solution. Search Google and you will get a good explanation by Thomas Kyte https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022

Comment: I am well aware about such issues. here I am just oversimplyfiying the thing, because my main focus was to point out the programming error.

Comment: @Carlo Sirna-I tried your method as u said .But now it is inserting 550000 rows and rest 18388 rows is left out.

Comment: my bad: use "EXIT WHEN v_t_spr.COUNT = 0" i overlooked it.

Comment: If it's not a one-off job then they should size their system for their needs. If it's a regular job then maybe consider a nologging insert with subsequent backup. If they don't have any money then use PostgreSQL and spend the Oracle license on hardware instead. Committing in a cursor is doubly-bad advice when you address it to a person who doesn't understand that SQL is better in 99.9% of cases than PL/SQL.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I don't use this technique in code that is part of the normal lifetime of the application. I use it only when I have to update/upgrade data structures. it is always an "one-off"

Comment: @CarloSirna sounds like NOLOGGING + backup may be the answer. All things considered, it's faster to code and execute, and less bug-prone.

Comment: @Nikhil: anyway you should take in serious consideration if you really need that approach. all the comments I received are well founded.

Comment: Just a little note: i use that kind of loop mostly in the  scripts i use for upgrading the data structure used by my application. This application  is deployed on more than 300 servers of different kinds and size (we range from installatos used only by 3 people to others used by 600 users). Most of the times i use it for performing long updates of new colums using data calculated on existing tables. (continues...)

Comment: (...  Continued )  my main concern during database structure upgrades is exactly to avoid the atomicity of such updates: i don't want a 2 hours update command to be entirely rolled back in case of a single row that causes some problem and have to wait the rollback to complete and then to start over again.  We have a limited timeframe for complting the upgrade. (continues)

Comment: So we rather write these loops in a way that they update all the possible rows that can be updated, we use a where condition that skips rows that hsve already been processed,  in order to be able to re-execte them after we address the problems that made those rows fail.  As I said we have 300 databases to be updated and some of our customers even have their own "IT"  team who messes with the database. We can't predict all the possible problems. And our main concern is to have the new version of the application up and running as soon as possible.

Comment: Most of the problems we meet can be  safely fixed afterwards,  especially if they are in hisyorical data that is not crucial for daily OLTP operations

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `EXIT WHEN c_sprdsht%NOTFOUND` (this is the cause of your missing rows), instead use `EXIT WHEN v_t_spr.COUNT = 0`

Comment: limit.COUNT is giving an error.I think syntax is incorrect